# How to insert multiple String in an Array

Tags: c++, arrays, string

In C++ how can I insert multiple string in an array and print it, like:

```
Array[] = {"One", "Two", "Three", "Four".......};
```

I want to print them according to their index location.

Thank you.

Comment: Show us what you've tried so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use raw array, should be:

```
std::string strArr[] = { "One","Two","Three","Four" };
for (size_t i = 0; i < sizeof(strArr) / sizeof(std::string); i++)
{
    std::cout << strArr[i] << "  ";
}
std::cout << std::endl;
```

---

It's better to use `vector` instead of raw array:

```
std::vector<std::string> strVec = { "One","Two","Three","Four" };
for (size_t i = 0; i < strVec.size(); i++)
{
    std::cout << strVec[i] << "  ";
}
std::cout << std::endl;
```

---

Another way to traverse `vector` is to use iterator:

```
for (auto itr = strVec.begin(); itr != strVec.end(); itr++)
{
    std::cout << *itr << "  ";
}
std::cout << std::endl;
```

Comment: Good solution I think.i

Answer (score 0):

You can use standard vector to achieve your goal.
`std::vector<std::string> stringVector = {"One","Two","Three","Four"}<br/>`

std::vector can also be extended after its allocated.